# Custom application settings

Tags: c#, static, settings, application-settings

I want to be able to have a Settings class that is available throughout the entire application, however I still want to be able to test that the settings object gets populated. Most of the settings come from the registry.

At the moment I have this but I'm not sure where to populate that, so that I can mock the service used to populate it.

```
public class Program {
    public static Settings SystemSettings = new SystemSettings();

    public void Main(string[] args) {
         SystemSettings = new RegistryService().GetRegSettings();
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a singleton class ,all class in your application can access to it

```
public class Settings
{
    private static Settings systemSettings;
    public static Settings SystemSettings 
    {
        get
        {
            if (systemSettings == null)
                systemSettings = new Settings();
            return systemSettings;
        }
    }
    public int SettingValue1{ get; set; }
    private Settings()
    {
        SettingValue1 = 1;//from registery or somewhere
    }


}
```

ans use this class easily

```
int k = Settings.SystemSettings.SettingValue1;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to abstract your underlying settings storage, in this case windows registry and have your settings controller call your abstraction.

Best way would be to inject your storage abstraction using a constructor. that way you could have your abstraction (Windows Register) mocked which would allow you to test your settings population.